# Webbrowser Cannot open Google Meet

Tags: c#

I made application windows form in c# and I want to add a web browser in order to open google meet in the application without opening my browser at all.

I made the button to open it but my web browser gives me the message meet doesn't work in compatibility view

Can anyone please help me fix this? I tried for 2 days to search on google how to make it work but I don't find anything useful.

[image]

Comment: `but my web browser` what web browser? Which control did you add? Which version of Windows Forms are you using? The old WebBrowser control uses IE and won't work with *any* site requiring modern features. You'll have to use the new [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) control which uses Edge Chromium

Comment: I am trying to make my app open modern features. I installed Chromium but I don't know how to apply it so it works.